# add custom font to a cordova project

Tags: cordova, fonts

I have a custom fonts that I would like to use in my app.

The font name is myfont and the files with the extension are  (myfont.eot,.myfont.svg,myfont.ttf,myfont.woff,myfont.woff2) and they are copied to  IOS and android asset folder when I do a cordova build. However, when I open the app on the device I don't see the new font display.

I do see the new fond display when I run the app from safari browser on the mac.

here is the snippet from my CSS file

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    font-family: 'myfont';
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Is there something else I need to do in order to see this new font on the android and iOS device

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `@font-face` in your CSS.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "my-font";
  src: url("../assets/myfonts.ttf");  // Give relative path to your css file.
}
```

Add  code to your css file at top.
And then you can easily use font-family `my-font` where ever you need.

Example:

CSS

```
.class-myfont { 
    font-family: my-font;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="class-myfont">Hello there</span>
```

Comment: NOTE: You MUST use the keyword __@font-face__.   

It is specifically for adding fonts.

Comment: @pashute `@font-face` is used to defined font-family. The code above is worked for me in so many cases.

Comment: Yes I agree. I was just pointing out that you cannot use any other name for the variable. You cannot write: ```@whatever { font-family: "my-font" ...``` etc. You must use the exact term: ```@font-face { font-family: "my-font" ...``` etc. And then everything will work.