# Fonts are Loading Randomly on Cordova App for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

We have a `Cordova` Web app (`HTML`, `JS` and `CSS`) and for some reasons on High end devices such as iPhone XS and XR the fonts sometimes are not loading.

I boot the app and fonts are not loading, I minimize the APP come back again and the fonts are okay.

Sometimes I open the app and everything is fine! On iPhone, 8, 7, 6 and SE, we don't get this bugs at all. It's completely random.

I change the order where the SaSS file are imported and same thing happens

Here's how we call the fond via the SaSS:

```
    @include font-face("dosisbold", "../fonts/dosis/dosis-bold-webfont", $__file-formats: woff2 woff ttf);
    @include font-face("dosissemibold", "../fonts/dosis/dosis-semibold-webfont", $__file-formats: woff2 woff ttf);
    @include font-face("dosisextrabold", "../fonts/dosis/dosis-extrabold-webfont", $__file-formats: woff2 woff ttf);

@mixin font-face( $__font-family, $__file-path, $__weight: normal, $__style: normal, $__file-formats: eot woff2 woff ttf svg ) {

    // Possible font formats
    $formats: (
        eot   : "#{$__file-path}.eot?#iefix" format("embedded-opentype"),
        woff2 : "#{$__file-path}.woff2" format("woff2"),
        woff  : "#{$__file-path}.woff" format("woff"),
        ttf   : "#{$__file-path}.ttf" format("truetype"),
        svg   : "#{$__file-path}.svg##{$__font-family}" format("svg")
    );


    // Creates the font sources
    $fonts-src: ();
    @each $formats_key, $formats_values in $formats {
        @if index($__file-formats, $formats_key) != null {
            $fonts-src: append($fonts-src, url(nth($formats_values, 1)) nth($formats_values, 2), comma);
        }
    }


    // Outputs the @font-face rule
    @font-face { font-family: $__font-family; font-weight: $__weight; font-style: $__style; src: $fonts-src; }
}
```

Comment: Try the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269174/add-custom-font-to-a-cordova-project

Comment: This is exactly what we do... it seems different from the code I post but it's a mixin.

Comment: That means you are creating the font-face mixing and you should be sharing its content into the question in hopes to receive an answer.

Comment: My mistake! I edit my question!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your mixing could be like the following:

```
@mixin font-face($style-name, $filepath, $category:"") {

    @font-face {
        font-family: "#{$style-name}";
        src: url($filepath + ".woff2") format('woff2'), url($filepath + ".woff") format('woff'), url($filepath + ".ttf")  format('truetype'), ;
    }

    %#{$style-name} {
        font: {
            @if $category == "" {
              family: "#{$style-name}";
              weight: normal;
            }
            @else {
              family: "#{$style-name}", #{$category};
            }
        }
    }
}

$family: 'dosis';
$file: 'dosis-bold-webfont';
$filepath: "fonts/" + $family + "/" + $file;
@include font-face('dosis', $filepath , 'serif');
```

This will produce:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "dosis";
  src: url("fonts/dosis/dosis-bold-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("fonts/dosis/dosis-bold-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/dosis/dosis-bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Is this what you were searching for?

Comment: The main problems is the font loading randomly on iOS! Boot 10 times the app 8 times the font is loading perfect and 2 times no fonts! So I guess my mixins is good because everything work just fine! But Ill give a shot at your code!

Comment: Same thing happed! :(

Comment: Mmhh. Do the following experiment. Just make this part pure CSS and test it as you just did. Let's confirm that the issue is related with the SaSS code by ruling it out first.